# Window Service is not able to restart even though Recovery option is configured

Tags: windows-services, recovery

In my Window Service if Service is enable to connect to SQL Server it throws an exception and windows service will not start. To overcome this situation I have set recovery option of Windows Service to First Failure, Second Failure to Restart the Service, Reset fail count after 1 day and Restart Service to 0 minutes.

What I want is when service throws an exception(unhandled) service should go for recovery option which I have configured and should try to restart the service. But this doesnt work.

After configuring service for recovery option if I got to the Task Manager and manually end the process then only this recovery option gets applied.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

If we call `Environment.Exit( -1 )` it send signal to SCM that service is crashed and Recovery option will get respect.

Hope this will help others like me.